# Получить количество подписчиков инстаграм аккаунта БЕЗ API

Tags: php

Я новичок и для меня это очень важно. Сайт на php, нужно поле `<input type="text">` и кнопка "ok", после в поле я вставлю в поле ссылку на инстаграм аккаунт, например [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/animaniatvofficial/) и после нажатия кнопки "ok" рядом должно отобразится количество подписчиков в этом инстаграм аккаунте. Заранее благодарю за помощь!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="link" placeholder="Ссылка на инстаграм "></input><!--Ссылка на инстаграм аккаунт -->
        <button id="ok">OK</button><br> 
        <span id="totals"> Подписчиков: </span> <!-- Тут должно быть количество подписчиков инстаграм аккаунта. -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Получаете страницу, по DOM находите требуемый элемент и тянете его контент.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста написать как это сделать? Если не сложно.

Comment: Добавьте ваши наработки к вопросу ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/667378/edit))

Comment: Добавил, только что по быстрому набросал, мне нужен именно этот код, я его просто вставлю на мой сайт.

Comment: На фрирансе сделают всю работу за вас. Тут помогают тем, кто хочет делать сам

Comment: Я сейчас учусь, конечно же хочу сам, если можете, то отправьте ссылку на этот урок, посмотрев который я смогу это сделать, уже 2 дня мучаюсь.

Comment: Так вы не мучайтесь, вы работайте.

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете использовать какой-либо Dom парсер.
Ручками, можете так:
**file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/xxxxxxx');**

и с помощью **stristr** высекаете что вам надо (прям как Микеланджело).